# Parse class variables?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to c# language as I just started to use it several weeks ago, and I came across one simple problem with classes.I was sitting for good 30 minutes looking for answers and just couldn't figure out how to fix it.
This is my code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Plyta p1;
        Plyta p2;
        p1 = new Plyta(p1.ImtiIlgi(), p1.ImtiAuksti());


        p1.ImtiIlgi();
        Console.Write("\niveskite plytos ilgi - ");
        p1.PlytosIlgis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        p1.ImtiAuksti();
        Console.Write("\niveskite plytos auksti - ");
        p1.PlytosAukstis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

and the class file:

```
class Plyta
{
    private int ilgis,
                aukstis;

    public Plyta(int PlytosIlgis, int PlytosAukstis)
    {
        ilgis = PlytosIlgis;
        aukstis = PlytosAukstis;
    }


    public int ImtiIlgi() 
    {
        return ilgis;
    }

    public int ImtiAuksti()
    {
        return aukstis;
    }
}
```

and when I run it, it gives the following error:

> 'praktika.Plyta' does not contain a definition for 'PlytosIlgis' and no extension method 'PlytosIlgis' accepting a first argument of type 'praktika.Plyta' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I assume I'm writing the wrong variable to parse but whatever I thought of doesn't work, any help for a begginner? :)

Comment: Well yes... when you write ` p1.PlytosIlgis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` what do you expect that assignment to do? It sounds like you should be declaring properties `Iglis` and `Aukstis`.

Comment: You have no property defined for Plytosllgis

Comment: In fact, looking at your first class, there's a lot going on there which is odd. Will see how much I can help...

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confused about what your methods are doing, and when you're initializing objects. I suspect you actually want to do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Ask the user for the relevant data
        Console.WriteLine("iveskite plytos ilgi - ");
        int ilgis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("iveskite plytos auksti - ");
        int aukstis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Now we're in a position to create the object
        Plyta p1 = new Plyta(ilgis, aukstis);

        // And we can read the value back from the property
        Console.WriteLine(p1.Ilgis);
    }
}

class Plyta
{
    // These are public, read-only automatically-implemented properties
    public int Ilgis { get; }
    public int Aukstis { get; }

    public Plyta(int ilgis, int aukstis)
    {
        // Set the properties...
        Ilgis = PlytosIlgis;
        Aukstis = PlytosAukstis;
    }
}
```

(This uses C# 6's read-only automatically-implemented properties. Let me know if you're not using C# 5.)

Comment: I am using C# 5

Answer (score 4):

You have no public field or property called `PlytosIlgis` in your class `Plyta`.

It's only the name of a parameter to your constructor.

You need to declare a pair of public properties:

```
public int PlytosIlgis { get; set; }

public int PlytosAukstis { get; set; }
```

You code should then compile.

Though with two internal fields:

```
private int ilgis,
            aukstis;
```

You probably want to convert those into properties:

```
public int Ilgis { get; set; }

public int Aukstis { get; set; }
```

and change your calls to:

```
    p1.Ilgis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    p1.Aukstis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

You'll also need to rework the rest of your main function as you are trying to access properties of `p1` before it has been initialised. You'll get a NullReferenceException when you try to run the code.

Either add a constructor that takes no arguments or read the values into local variables first then pass them to the current constructor (as in Jon Skeet's answer):

```
    Console.WriteLine("iveskite plytos ilgi - ");
    int ilgis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("iveskite plytos auksti - ");
    int aukstis = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Plyta p1 = new Plyta(ilgis, aukstis);
```

The current calls:

```
    p1.ImtiIlgi();
    p1.ImtiAuksti();
```

do nothing as you're not assigning the value to anything,

Comment: is there any way to make ilgis and aukstis private? because i cant seem to work that out

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this code line:

```
p1 = new Plyta(p1.ImtiIlgi(), p1.ImtiAuksti());
```

you are declaring p1 and at the same time "using" it. Try using an empty constructor

```
 public Plyta(){}
```

or directly pass the parameters, like so:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

Plyta p1;
p1 = new Plyta(a, b);
```

Otherwise use getters and setters.